# Get dimensions image in Assets Android

Tags: android, image, assets

In Asset Android an image.png, how can get dimensions?

I've try, this but doesn't work.

```js
String image = "my_image.png"

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(context.getAssets() +  "/" + image, options);
 // BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/other_dir/" + image, options);

    int width_t = options.outWidth;
    int height_t = options.outHeight;
```

If image is in /other_dir/, I can get dimensions, but not in Asset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
AssetManager asset = context.getAssets();
InputStream is; 
try {
    is = asset.open("my_image.png");
} catch (IOException e) {
return null;
}
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);

int width_t = options.outWidth;
int height_t = options.outHeight;
```

Comment: Works perfect, thank you. I changed: InputStream is = null;